# What does RUN rm -Rf do in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I am having trouble with the company legacy code. Dockerfile

```
FROM mycomp/tech:2.13

RUN rm -Rf /opt/app/src/api

COPY src/ /opt/app/src/
COPY config.json /opt/app/config.json
```

What does `RUN rm -Rf` serve for?
Why did the guy who wrote Dockerfile add it?
How it will map into the container?

Comment: I mean, it does exactly what is written there, run `rm -Rf /opt/app/src` in the container. But seeing you know what a dockerfile is, that is probably known to you. So what is the real question here? We can't out of thin air read the mind of some unknown author of some unprovided dockerfile, so the "why" question is impossible to answer but with "they wanted to achieve the effect of `RUN rm -Rf /opt/app/src/`," and that's a tautology.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Few lines below,COPY src/ /opt/app/src/,how to copy to something that is removed?

Comment: Can you post the whole Dockerfile?

Comment: You're removing `/opt/app/src/api` and then copying to `/opt/app/src/`, how is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RUN rm -Rf /opt/app/src/api
```

runs `rm -Rf /opt/app/src/api` in the container, deleting `/opt/app/src/api` and its contents (but not `/opt/app/src`).

```
COPY src/ /opt/app/src/
```

[copies the `src` directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) in the build context to `/opt/app/src/`. This isn’t affected by the previous `rm -Rf`. This will work anyway even if `/opt/app/src/` doesn’t exist:

> If `<dest>` doesn’t exist, it is created along with all missing directories in its path.